# Accessing history of of commands typed within terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, history

I would like to access my terminal history. I tried `history`, however there are over 1900 lines of commands and I can't see all of the history due to the length of the commands.

It shows between 961-1942. I tried to write it in a text document over checking on terminal via `history > a.txt`. The text file only includes the commands between 961-1942.

Is there any way to access all of these 1942 entries?

Comment: How are you accessing the machine ? through putty? Check if there is any limit on the number of lines you can scroll

Comment: no pure linux terminal :)

Comment: check $HOME/.bash_history for full history

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the full history in `~/.bash_history`

For displaying convenience, consider `grep`ping it, to filter it, or at least piping to `less`

```
cat ~/.bash_history | grep somekeywordorregex | less
```

or just

```
cat ~/.bash_history | less
```

This works for bash. Other shells, may have history saved into different files (e.g. ash into ash_history). The file is usually `$HISTFILE` in bash and zsh. But not all shells support history or may have limited support (e.g. dash).